# Display year in the future

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an app that cannot display any year past 2016 in a drop down.

At the same time, and as time goes on, I need to display past years.

For example:

- in the year 2017, I will need to display 2016 and 2017.
- In the year 2018, I will need to display 2016, 2017, and 2018.
- And so on

So I have developed the following code to accomplish this.

Do you know of a better way to accomplish this in TSQL?

```
SELECT [Year] FROM (
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) AS 'Year'
UNION
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())) AS 'Year' WHERE YEAR(GETDATE()) > 2017
UNION
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(year,-2,GETDATE())) AS 'Year' WHERE YEAR(GETDATE()) > 2018
UNION
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(year,-3,GETDATE())) AS 'Year' WHERE YEAR(GETDATE()) > 2019
UNION
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(year,-4,GETDATE())) AS 'Year' WHERE YEAR(GETDATE()) > 2020
UNION
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(year,-5,GETDATE())) AS 'Year' WHERE YEAR(GETDATE()) > 2021
UNION
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(year,-6,GETDATE())) AS 'Year' WHERE YEAR(GETDATE()) > 2022
UNION
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(year,-7,GETDATE())) AS 'Year' WHERE YEAR(GETDATE()) > 2023
) x
ORDER BY [Year] DESC
```

Comment: why do this in TSQL? why not in code of app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, this will generate a list of Year from 2016 to current year

```
WITH CTE_TEST AS(
    SELECT 2016 AS NYEAR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NYEAR+1
    FROM    CTE_TEST
    WHERE NYEAR+1 <= YEAR(GETDATE())
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Year table that has all valid years you ever want the application to handle.

```
Select Year From Year
Where Year>=2016
AND Year<=DATEPART(Year,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Also be sure to document its purpose because otherwise someone in 5 years is going to say _"WTF do we need this table for?"_

Comment: Funny enough, tables like this are pretty useful. Ever try to find a gap in a numeric series? Makes a table full of numbers pretty useful. Or a CTE.

Comment: Instead of a year table i'd use a full calendar table including all dates of a year for a greater period, say 20-50 years. It is self-explanatory and can be used often. It will make your life much easier and enables to write simpler, more maintainable sql which is also more efficient. 30 years incl. all dates require only 136kb HD space, so nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with a calendar table it is simple:

```
SELECT [Year] = YEAR(c.Date)
FROM CalendarTable c 
WHERE YEAR(c.Date) >= 2016 AND YEAR(c.Date) <= YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(c.Date)
ORDER BY YEAR(c.Date)
```

[How to generate a calendar table](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3) (look for "Calendar table").

Answer (score 1):

You can create and consume an in-line numbers table like this:

```
-- Return all years starting from current year up to @YEAR
DECLARE @YEAR INT = 2011

SELECT y AS 'YEAR'
FROM (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
   FROM (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0) ) AS t1(n)
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0) ) AS t2(n)) AS x(i)    
CROSS APPLY (SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(year,-1*x.i,GETDATE()))) AS t(y)
WHERE y >= @YEAR
```

The in-line table used by the above query contains 5x5 = 25 rows. You can adjust it to suit your actual needs.